# ¿Cómo sumar por filas sin tener consideración a los valores missing/NA?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
datos
j      x   y   z
Luis   NA  2   4
María  2   NA  3
José   3   NA  NA
Saul   4   4   NA
```

Deseo sumar por filas, es decir, crear un nuevo vector en el cual se contenga la suma de los vectores `x`, `y` y `z`. He intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
datos$suma<-rowSums(datos[,-1])

# Pero el resultado de la suma es:

> datos$suma
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

Lo que me lleva a la pregunta si existe una función que me permita sumar omitiendo los `NA`. Es decir, que me resulte un data frame de la siguiente manera:

```
datos
j      x   y   z   suma
Luis   NA  2   4   6
María  2   NA  3   5
José   3   NA  NA  3
Saul   4   4   NA  8
```

**Gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowSums()` como muchas otras funciones, tienen un práctico parámetro `na.rm` que elimina de la suma los valores `NA` que hoy te esta provocando que el resultado final sea `NA`. Ejemplo:

```
> rowSums(cbind(1,NA))
[1] NA
> rowSums(cbind(1,NA), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Nuevamente!!!!